# Ubuntu server 18 problem with display manager - can't see GDM properly

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, gdm

[image]

Lenovo sr650 server with 2 graphical adapters :

1. Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200e
2. NVIDIA Corporation GV100GL [Tesla V100 PCIe 32GB]

After installing GDM - can't see it properly .
Please advice .

Comment: root@server:/etc/X11# lshw -C display
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: MGA G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1)
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 42
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=mgag200 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:d3000000-d3ffffff memory:d4a10000-d4a13fff memory:d4000000-d47fffff memory:d4a00000-d4a0ffff

Comment: *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GV100GL [Tesla V100 PCIe 32GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2f:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:2200-21ff iomemory:2280-227f irq:320 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:22000000000-227ffffffff memory:22800000000-22801ffffff

Comment: In the title you mention server 18 (implying a *snap* only Ubuntu Core 18 or like system), but you've also tagged 18.04 which is a different product (*deb* based).  Please clarify which is correct?  Are you using 18 & *snap* only, or *18.04* which is a *deb* based release?   Ubuntu has used *yy* based releases to mean *snap* only since 2016.   (Servers, both 18 or 18.04 are usually used *headless* with no monitors on, so does it matter if you can only use a single screen if they'll both be turned off anyway!)

Comment: Hi  18.04 Ubuntu Server

Comment: Please adjust your question to say 18.04 and not 18 (Ubuntu Core 18 is designed to fulfill small server roles... on devices, cloud etc.)

Answer (score -1):

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux It looks like it helped me and now I can see logon screen properly.

Configure GDM3:

> As a privileged administrator user use your text editor to perform the
> following changes of the GDM3 custom configuration file
> `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.
>
> From:
>
> ````
> #WaylandEnable=false ```
>
> To:
>
> ```none WaylandEnable=false ```
>
> By uncommenting the above line your system will use the Xorg display
> manager instead of Wayland next time it boots. Reboot your system to
> apply the changes.
> ````